# T-SQL VARCHAR(MAX) Truncated

Tags: t-sql

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR (MAX);

SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str + CHAR(10), '') +
       'EXECUTE CreateDeno ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) 
FROM   GL_To_Batch_Details
WHERE  TYPE = 'C' AND
       Deno_ID IS NULL;

--PRINT @str;--SELECT @str;
**EXEC(@str);**
```

*EDITED*

Does `EXECUTE` statement truncate strings to 8,000 chars like `PRINT`? How can I execute a dynamic SQL statement having more than 8,000 chars?

Any suggestion would be warmly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are confused, you can't `PRINT` more than 8000 characters, that doesn't mean that @str is being truncated

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific on the problem. Actually when EXECUTE produced the error, I used PRINT to see what was the dynamic T-SQL generated. In both cases, nvarchar(MAX) values had been truncated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`PRINT` is limited to 8k in output.

There is also an 8k limit in SSMS results pane.

Go to

**tools -> options -> query results**

to see the options.

To verify the length of the actual data, check:

`SELECT LEN(@str)`

Comment: Okay. PRINT is used here instead of EXEC to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: @Nick Bennet: [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332(v=SQL.90).aspx): In earlier versions of SQL Server, character strings are limited to 8,000 bytes. This requires concatenating large strings for dynamic execution. In SQL Server 2005, the varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) data types can be specified that allow for character strings to be up to 2 gigabytes of data.

Comment: I had to use NVARCHAR(MAX) data type along with sp_executesql in order to get it working. Could you please confirm the same thing can be achieved without using sp_executesql? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

When concatenating strings and the result is of type VARCHAR(MAX) and is over 8000 characters, *at least one* parameter and/or element being used in the concatenation need to be of the VARCHAR(MAX) type otherwise truncation will occur in the resultant string and will not be executable in an EXEC statement.

**Example:**

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX);
/* DECLARE @someItem AS VARCHAR(100); -- WILL CAUSE TRUNCATION WHEN @sql HAS LEN > 8000 */
DECLARE @someItem AS VARCHAR(MAX); -- All string variables need to be VARCHAR(MAX) when concatenating to another VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @someItem = 'Just assume the resulting @sql variable goes over 8000 characters...';
SET @sql = 'SELECT Something FROM Somewhere WHERE SomeField = ''' + @someItem + '''';

EXEC (@sql);
--PRINT @sql;
```

More information on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx).

> "If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of
>   8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the
>   strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not
>   occur."

Answer (score 2):

The [default length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) of a `varchar` is 30 characters:

```
CAST (ID AS VARCHAR)
```

Is it possible that `id` is longer than 30 characters?

Comment: No, it is not possible for ID being longer than 30 chars.

Comment: It is a good practice to never use the default length, there are other times where the default len is 1.

Answer (score 2):

The `PRINT` command is certainly limited to 8000 chars, irrespective of the length of the output (or whether it is varchar(max)). To work around this you need to output the string in chunks of `<8000` chars

---

Update: In answer to your edit, exec doesn't limit the string length. I've put together the following example to show this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR (MAX);


;WITH CTE_Count AS
(
    select counter = 1
    union all
    select counter = counter+1
    from CTE_Count
    Where counter < 2000

)
SELECT             
    @str=COALESCE(@str + CHAR (10) ,
        '' ) + 'select value=' + CAST (counter AS VARCHAR) 
from
    CTE_Count

Option (MAXRECURSION 0)

PRINT len(@str);--SELECT @str;

exec (@str)
```

Running this prints the length as 34892 chars, and all 2000 execute statements do run (be warned, it may take a few mins!)

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you concatenate literals if one is not a varchar(max) the result ill be "implicit casted" to varchar(8000).

To generate a literal varchar(max) all parts must be varchar(max).
Note: It happened to me doing updates on varchar(max) columns, never tested with the EXEC command.

Also as noted in previous answers the print command holds a limit but you can try selecting that variable instead of printing it. (also ther's a limit on that select length you can configure on MS-SMS)

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to see what I was sending to Exec, and was confused by the PRINT limit.   Had to write a proc to print in chunks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[KFX_PrintVarcharMax] 
    @strMax varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
        @index int = 0,
        @start int = 1,
        @blkSize int = 2000;


    WHILE @Start < LEN(@strMax)
    BEGIN
        IF @start + @blkSize >= LEN(@strMax)
        BEGIN
            -- If remainder is less than blocksize print the remainder, and exit.
            PRINT SUBSTRING(@strMax, @start, @blkSize)
            BREAK;
        END
        -- Else find the next terminator (beyond the blksize)
        SET @index = CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), @strMax, @start + @blkSize);
        if @index >= @start
        BEGIN
            PRINT SubString(@strMax, @start, @index - @start + 1)
            SET @start = @index + 1;
            SET @blkSize  = CASE WHEN @start + 2000 < LEN(@strMax) THEN 2000 
                            ELSE LEN(@strMax) - @start + 1 END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- No char(10) found.  Just print the rest.
            PRINT SUBSTRING(@strMax, @start, LEN(@strMax))
            BREAK;
        END 
    END

END
```