# How does SQL Server store more than 4000 characters in NVARCHAR(max)?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, nvarchar

I have defined a stored procedure that has a parameter of type `NVARCHAR(max)` and I process that string in my `stored procedure`. I know that max of `nvarchar` is 4000. But I have passed a string with 5700 characters to my sp with no errors. Is it possible?

Comment: NVARCHAR(MAX) can store more than 2 GB of data .Kindly refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639948/sql-nvarchar-and-varchar-limits

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ] Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000

Comment: @breceivemail: if you read on the page you linked to, it also says: *max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB).*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes it is possible** - according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx):

> **nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]**
>
> *Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. **max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB).** The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying.*

So if you specify `nvarchar(max)` you can store up to **1 billion** 2-byte Unicode characters. That's Leo Tolstoj's *War and Peace* well over a hundred times over ....

SQL Server stores those *max* columns into special structures internally, which makes it possible to get around the 8K limit of the SQL Server pages. It works - but it's more effort than just storing a few hundred bytes on a page, so this storage system does pose more strain on SQL Server - use it with care, use it only when you **really** need to (and most definitely don't just make all your columns `(n)varchar(max)`, just because you're lazy!)

Check out this really good article on Simple Talk: [What's the Point of Using VARCHAR(n) Anymore?](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/) - it explains very nicely how `(max)` datatypes are different and less suited for smaller strings - use only when really needed!

Answer (score 1):

You Could Try

```
Declare @SQL as nvarchar(Max)
    ,@SQL2 as nvarchar(Max)

-- Just Sample
-- each variable max 4000 character, so be wise in splitting your syntax

Set @SQL  = 'Select * '
Set @SQL2 = 'From table A'

EXEC (@SQL+@SQL2)
```

Note if your dynamic string length more than > 8000 character you should split into 3 variables'

this should works, because i was have same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are concating your string then you have to concate it like below.

```
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @qry = N'SELECT * FROM Table1 t1';
SET @qry = @qry + N'INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col2'
SET @qry = @qry + N'INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col3'

EXEC sp_executeSQL @qry
```

In above example even if the characters of the concated string exceeds 4000 characters then also it will be added into the variable and the limit is upto 2GB.