# Performance impact of concatenating NVARCHAR with varchar and ''(single quote single quote)

Tags: sql-server

What is the datatype of `''` in sql server and does performance hit when concatenating `nvarchar`, `varchar`, and `''`.

What are the implicit conversions here?

Comment: The exact datatype depends on whether or not the string literal has the `N` prefix and the length of the string. Concatenating a string without the `N` prefix that is between 4K and 8K characters long to an nvarchar will [always cause truncation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639948/sql-nvarchar-and-varchar-limits/12639972#12639972) as it gets cast to `nvarchar(4000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `varchar`. Use

```
select sql_variant_property('','BaseType')
```

Comment: Is there any similar function which catches nvarchar(max) too