# SQL Server varchar(max) only 8k characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, varchar

I'm trying to execute a SQL query stored in a string. But the `varchar(max)` limit is only 8000. How can I store more than 8000 characters in SQL Server?

```
declare @query varchar(max)

set @query = 'select * from ....... (22,000+ characters)'

exec(@query)
```

Thanks!

Comment: please try searching before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639948/sql-nvarchar-and-varchar-limits

Comment: a sql with more than 8000 characters? I don't think it's good idea for execution, use temporary table instead?