# Varchar(Max) is not working in Exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, varcharmax

I have a `variable` which has `SQL` string stored in it and am executing it through `exec()`

```
Declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = Concat('select...',@var,'..') -- large string 

exec (@sql)
```

but am getting error saying

> Incorrect syntax near sometext

It is because the variable `@sql` cannot hold the entire string. So I fixed by splitting the string into two different variables and executed it

```
Declare @sql1 varchar(max),@sql2 varchar(max)

set @sql1 = 'select...' 
set @sql2 = ' from sometable join....'

exec (@sql1+@sql2)
```

I checked the data length of `@sql1+ @sql2`

```
Select Datalength(@sql1+ @sql2)
```

It returned `14677`

Now question is why `varchar(max)` cannot store `14677` bytes of information? When the documents says it can store upto `2GB` of data

Comment: That is odd and unlikely. Did you `select @sql` to check if the string is really correct.

Comment: You're probably hiding some sins where you've just written `--long string`, such as combining multiple short string literals using `+`. A `varchar(max)` *variable* can actually hold even *more* than 2GB, assuming SQL Server 2008 or later.

Comment: @juergend - yes, When I do `Select @sql` it is returning only the part of string

Comment: This is the [sin I'm referring to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx): "If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of 8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not occur." - if you just have two string literals, neither will be a large value type in itself, and the variable you'll *eventually* store the result in is not part of the equation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL NVARCHAR and VARCHAR Limits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639948/sql-nvarchar-and-varchar-limits)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - But I did not use `+` for string concatenation inside my dynamic sql. I have used `CONCAT` function

Comment: Well, the documentation for [`CONCAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh231515.aspx) is hardly mysterious about this either - "If none of the input arguments is of a supported large object (LOB) type, then the return type is truncated to 8000 in length, regardless of the return type". It would be much easier for us to point to these type of errors, though, if we could *see* the code which contains the error, rather than being forced to guess about it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Got it.. That is the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Code is so big that's why didn't post it. Now I understood the reason. It is not because of `@sql` variable and it is due to  `CONCAT` function. Fixed it by adding `set @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'select..')'`

Comment: but where you have used concat function in your question? @Prdp

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Here user is not using Concat function know

Comment: @Srinath - Am using `concat` function. Updated the question. I have mentioned it in my previous comment so he clarified it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably this you are running against:

```
DECLARE @part1 VARCHAR(5000)=REPLICATE('a',5000);
DECLARE @part2 VARCHAR(5000)=REPLICATE('a',5000);

SELECT DATALENGTH(@part1),DATALENGTH(@part2),DATALENGTH(@part1+@part2);
```

The result is 5000,5000,**8000**

If one of the summands is a `MAX` type, you'll get the expected result

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(@part1),DATALENGTH(@part2),DATALENGTH(CAST(@part1 AS VARCHAR(MAX))+@part2);
```

The result is 5000,5000,**10000**

This is often seen in connection with

- string concatenation
- usage of (older) functions returning `VARCHAR(8000)` as former max length
- column definitions

### UPDATE Same with `CONCAT`

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(@part1),DATALENGTH(@part2),DATALENGTH(CONCAT(@part1,@part2));
SELECT DATALENGTH(@part1),DATALENGTH(@part2),DATALENGTH(CONCAT(CAST(@part1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)),@part2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach of creating two varchar(max) data elements and combining them via "exec (@sql1+@sql2)" works and I appreciate the suggestion.  I ran into the same issue and will be using this trick in the future.

For me, one varchar(max) data element got truncated when attempted to be executed.  Split it into two varchar(max) data elements (no syntax change) and executed without issue.