# Dealing wih very long varchar/nvarchar variables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a script that creates the email body in html format, so that it can be sent with `sp_send_dbmail`.

So I have three variables: `@tableHTML1 varchar(8000)`, `@tableHTML2 varchar(8000)`, `@tableHtmlComplete varchar(max)`.

After the tsql script is executed, the len of `@tableHTML1` is 4768, `@tableHTML2` is 4594. Since the `@body` parameter of `sp_send_dbmail` can only receive one variable, I ended up doing `set @tableHtmlComplete = @tableHTML1 + @tableHTML2`. Unfortunately, the len of `@tableHtmlComplete` is 8000, since that's the max size of a varchar variable.

So what can I do in this case? I need to email the contents of @tableHTML1 plus @tableHTML2.

I will only consider another solution if what I'm trying to do above is not feasible.

Thanks.

Comment: 8000 bytes isnt the max size.  VARCHAR(max) can hold 2gb of data.

Comment: So why does it cut the text at 8000 bites?

Comment: Bytes not bites. And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639948/sql-nvarchar-and-varchar-limits/12639972#12639972

Comment: I ended up just declaring all variables as `varchar(max)` and the email was sent correctly.

Comment: I was just under the impression that concatenating two `varchar(max)` into one `varchar(max)` would hit some limit. I was obviously wrong.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I know. I mistyped here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert them to `varchar(max)` before concatenating them:

```
DECLARE @tableHTML1 varchar(8000), @tableHTML2 varchar(8000), @tableHtmlComplete varchar(max)

SET @tableHTML1 = REPLICATE('a',4768);
SET @tableHTML2 = REPLICATE('a',4594);
SET @tableHtmlComplete = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@tableHTML1) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@tableHTML2);

SELECT DATALENGTH(@tableHtmlComplete);
```

Result: 9362

Answer (score 0):

As a side note: you can simplify Lamak's solution by converting just the first value to varchar(max) like so:

```
SET @tableHtmlComplete = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@tableHTML1) + @tableHTML2;
```