The error occurs when the dynamic SQL query is only running for 128 lines, not 150 lines, despite setting the table name and query length to MAX
I was using a dynamic SQL query and I come across an error. Find below the code:
DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(128); -- Setting tablename dynamic and its length 128 characters
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR (MAX); -- Setting dynamic sql query length maximum

SET @tablename = 'table_name_123' + FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()), 'MMMdd_yyyy')
SET @sql = '
     --------- 150 line code ----------
';
print(@sql)
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

Problem: My query is only running for 128 lines not for 150 lines.
Note: I am using SSMS
Since, I have already declared length of SQL as MAX, why it is taking automatic length of 128 which was previously specified for tablename. When I changed length of tablename from 128 to MAX, whole code was working well.

This sometimes happens when you concatenate your string with shorter ones, or if you mix varchar and nvarchar strings. Cast every concated string to nvarchar(max) and use N' literals for strings and see if it works better. Or use CONCAT function. You can also break down the code into multiple SETs. Also, PRINT truncates the output to 4000 chars. Finally, 150 lines long dynamic sql? Maybe you're just doing something wrong, code like 'table_name_123' + FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()), 'MMMdd_yyyy') is a sign of worse things to come.

You don't need to cast every value to an nvarchar(MAX), @siggemannen . I often, for long dynamic scripts, start off with CONVERT(nvachar(MAX),N''') + ... as then every string concatenated afterwards is implicitly converted to MAX length

What is this dynamic SQL trying to do in the first place? 128 lines is a very strong indication it's doing something wrong. The very fact it's trying to generate a table name like this, even using the US-only date format, means it's trying to do manual "partitioning" wrong, instead of using actual table partitioning or even partitioned views. A single view using UNION ALL can combine all the "partition" tables in one.

A partitioned view can be updatable. If the various tables have proper constraints and indexes, the query optimizer will pick the correct table for modifications or querying automatically. If eg every table has a Date column constrained to a single date, the optimizer will be able to pick the correct table based on the value of a WHERE Date=@someDate clause.

Getting the overly long string to run is like using aspirin for toothache. Sure, the pain can go away for a few hours, but won't fix the real problem. Whether you're trying to deal with lots of data or multitenancy, SQL Server has far better solutions for this already.

Regarding the truncation issue then if you use CONCAT instead of + then as long as one of the arguments somewhere is max then the return type is max. You don't have to worry about it being one of the first two arguments as CONCAT is an N-ary function rather than a binary function. For this reason it is also more efficient

@MartinSmith do you know why this truncation happens? For me it's a bug, because sql server doesn't generally cast the types into smaller sizes

@ThomA agree, I was "brought up" on not using CONCAT so sometimes I still use the old solutions, old habits die hard

@siggemannen If you concatenate a + b + c and a and b are nvarchar and are not max datatypes then they will get possible truncation to 4000 characters  regardless of whether c is a max type. Presumably something like that is going on here. nvarchar(max) + varchar(n) is also a nasty case  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12639972/73226

It's not a bug, @siggemannen , it's just implicit conversion and that SQL Server works "left to right" with the concatenation. So, for example. REPLICATE('A',8000) + 'BCD' + CONVERT(varchar(MAX),'Z') would result in a string with 8000 A's and a single Z, the BCD would have been truncated; the conversion to MAX didn't occur until after the final concatenation was resolved. db<>fiddle

I'm pretty sure i've had a(max) + b(n) truncated but yeah, it could've been the varchar => nvarchar-conversion thingy. CONCAT is the way to go and make sure nvarchar(max) goes first

TBH I did find this question unclear though as there seems to be some confusion of 128 lines and 128 characters and there is no runnable code for us to reproduce any issue ourselves - hence VTC

The problem, as siggemannen mentions, is still likely truncation.
You have declared your variable, @sql, as an nvarchar(MAX), however, the values you are concatenating to then be assigned to your variable are not of MAX length. When you concatenate values, they are not implicitly concatenated to MAX length if the number of characters exceeds 8,000 bytes. For example. SELECT REPLICATE('A',7999) + 'AA'; would only return 8000 A characters, not 8001, as the data type of the string would be a varchar(8000), and so the final A is truncated.
The same is likely happening here; you are concatenating many non-MAX string and expecting a MAX length value. That your variable is a MAX isn't relevant here, as the assignment (and conversion) occurs after the expression is defined. If it didn't, then something like DECLARE @Date date = '2022' + '10' + '12'; would generate an error, as none of those string are valid dates on their own.
I find the easiest way to solve this problem is to start off my concatenating an empty MAX length value (of the correct type) to the string at the start. This means that every value concatenated afterwards is then also implicitly converted to a MAX value:
SET @sql = CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), N'') + 
           N'
     --------- 150 line code ----------
';

