# EXECUTE @Var character limit SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been looking all over for an answer to this, but nothing is explicit so hopefully someone knows off the top of their head.

When using `EXECUTE` with a `VARCHAR(MAX)` variable, is there a character limit? I've done some experimenting and it seems that when load a variable and then call `EXECUTE @var`, there is a character limit on what is actually passed through to the server. When calling `EXECUTE` without the variable and just building the string there, everything appears to work.... is there a reason for this? The error message returned is:

> *The Name ' (insert around 643 out of 881 characters of my SQL statement variable here) ' is not a valid identifier*

Does anybody know anything about why this might be happening? `EXECUTE @var` fails, `EXECUTE 'string'` works...

Comment: what is your String you're trying to execute?

Comment: Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.

Comment: Not sure where you learned your syntax, but you want to use `EXEC(@var);` (those parentheses are important!) or, better yet, `EXEC sp_executesql @var;`. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx In the future, it's useful to list the code you're using in addition to the error message you receive.

Comment: (Also, you'll want to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for dynamic SQL, not `VARCHAR(MAX)`.)

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that! You are absolutely correct, I needed to put () around my variable. I'm going into the bad corner now....

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! (strangely my previous dynamic proc had the proper syntax, and I STILL didn't catch it... more coffee for me!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought is was:
exec @mystr 
--assumes the string is a procedure name and is limited to 8000 bytes

exec (@mystr) 
--has the 2 gigabyte limit.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2008, the limit seems to be strings up to 2 GB, according to msdn:

> **Using EXECUTE with a Character String**
>
> In earlier versions of SQL Server, character strings are limited to 8,000 bytes. This requires concatenating large strings for dynamic execution. In SQL Server, the varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) data types can be specified that allow for character strings to be up to 2 gigabytes of data.

[Here is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with all the information.

If you are having problems, it may be the way you are concatenating the strings on your variable.

Comment: To expand on the statement, "If you are having problems, it may be the way you are concatenating the strings on your variable."

Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29686775/667632.