# SQL Server is not printing more than 8000 length of data

Tags: sql-server

The following code return not more than 8000 character in SQL server 2012. Is there a possible method to print more than 8000 characters

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CAST('SELECT * FROM ' + TableName  AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
  FROM Table1

PRINT(@SQL)
```

Comment: I think the problem lies with the internal `SELECT` statement.  Can you select and cast individual columns instead of trying to cast `SELECT *`?

Comment: This is actually a limitation in SSMS see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392161/t-sql-varcharmax-truncated) answer

Comment: Try to use EXEC
(
  '
   --your sql script here
  '
)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The final result should be a list of select queries for all the tables present in TableName column of table table1. the above code prints upto 8000 chars where in the end, the select query is printed partially. I am only using one column from the table table1. Can you please be more clear?

Comment: can you please tell what is the output for your query for print len(@sql)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
PRINT SUBSTRING(@SQL,0,8000)
PRINT SUBSTRING(@SQL,8001,8000)
PRINT SUBSTRING(@SQL,16001,8000)
```

etc

Comment: Thank you Peter. The problem occurs only for printing. But when I put EXEC(@SQL) all the contents are getting executed.

Comment: Peter? :) Your question was about printing - so my answer is about printing. That is one way to print what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies with how you insert the data.  I was able to get 8001 characters returned with your code with the following table creation and insert.

```
Drop Table #Test
Create Table #Test (Test Varchar(Max))
Insert #Test Values (Convert(Varchar(Max),Space(7999)) + 'xy')

Select * From #Test

DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX) = '#Test'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CAST('SELECT Test FROM ' + @TableName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FROM #Test

PRINT(@SQL)
```

Note how the value is cast as varchar(max) on insertion.