# Read columns in SQL tables which are the result of another query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, union, dynamic-sql

I need to check that all **primary key** columns do have **all values in uppercase**.

So, I have a first request which returns me the table-field pairs which are part of PK.

```
SELECT table_name, field_name FROM dico WHERE pkey > 0;
```

(`dico` is some table which gives that information.  No need to look it up in the SQL Schema…)

And, for all those pairs `tx`/`fx` listed from that first query above, I need to look for values which would not be uppercased.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 't1', 'f1', f1 FROM t1 WHERE f1 <> UPPER(f1) UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 't2', 'f2', f2 FROM t2 WHERE f2 <> UPPER(f2) UNION ALL
...
SELECT DISTINCT 'tn', 'fn', fn FROM tn WHERE fn <> UPPER(fn);
```

(I'm putting the table name and field name as "strings" in the output, so that I know from where the wrong values are coming.)

As you see, I do have the code for both requests, but I do not know how to combine them (if possible, in a generic way that would work for both SQL Server and Oracle).

Can you give me some idea on how to finish that?

Comment: Add constrains that only pass upper case values.

Comment: This is rather tricky because Oracle is -- by default -- case sensitive, but SQL Server is not.

Comment: I can't add constraints. I need to check what's in there -- some things are imported via external systems, Excel files, etc.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  If I need to write 2 different queries, because of the case sensitivity, so be it. That's not a hard requirement, but a nice-to-have (the same request usable in both environnements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that I could think of is to use a statement block that contains a loop.

Unfortunately, the structure of a statement block will be different for every different database system (the one for SQL Server will be different for Oracle).

I wrote an example using SQL Server further below (fiddle link is at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=85cd786adf32247da1aa73c0341d1b72).

Just in case, the dynamic query gets very long (possibly longer than the limit of `varchar`, which is 8000 characters), SQL Server has `varchar(max)` that can hold up to 2GB (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This can be used for `@DynamicQuery`, replacing `VARCHAR(3000)` in the example below (modified/alternative fiddle link, just to show that the data type really exists and can be used, is at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7fbb5d130aad35e682d8ce7ffaf09ede).

Please note that the example is not using your exact queries because I do not have access to the exact same data as the one you have (e.g. I cannot test the example using `dico` table because I do not have access to that table).
However, I made the example so that it uses a similar basic structure of logic from your queries, so that later on it can be customised to suit your exact need/scenario (e.g. by changing the table names and field names to match the ones that you use, as well as by adding the `WHERE` clause as you need).

In the example, your 1st query will be run immediately and the result will be handled by a cursor.

After that, a loop (using `WHILE` statement/structure) will loop through the cursor for the result of the 1st query to dynamically build the 2nd query (inserting the table names and the field names from the 1st query).

Note that at this point, the 2nd query is still being built, not being run yet.

Eventually, after the loop has finished, the resulting/compiled 2nd query will be run/executed (using the `EXEC` command).

```
-- START of test data creation.
create table TableA
( message varchar(200)
);

insert into TableA([message]) values ('abc');
insert into TableA([message]) values ('def');

create table TableB
( message varchar(200)
);

insert into TableB([message]) values ('ghi');
insert into TableB([message]) values ('jkl');
-- END of test data creation.



-- START of dynamic SQL
declare @TableAndFieldDetails CURSOR
declare @TableName VARCHAR(50)
declare @FieldName VARCHAR(50)
declare @DynamicQuery VARCHAR(3000) = ''
begin
  SET @TableAndFieldDetails = CURSOR FOR
  -- START of the 1st query
  SELECT  [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME,
          [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME
  FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%message%'
  -- END of the 1st query

  -- START of dynamically building the 2nd query
  OPEN @TableAndFieldDetails
  FETCH NEXT FROM @TableAndFieldDetails INTO @TableName, @FieldName
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    IF @DynamicQuery <> ''
    BEGIN
      SET @DynamicQuery += ' UNION ALL '
    END

    -- The one line right below is each individual part/element of the 2nd query
    SET @DynamicQuery += 'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''', ''' + @FieldName + ''', ' + @FieldName + ' FROM ' + @TableName

    FETCH NEXT FROM @TableAndFieldDetails INTO @TableName, @FieldName
  END
  CLOSE @TableAndFieldDetails
  DEALLOCATE @TableAndFieldDetails
  -- END of dynamically building the 2nd query

  EXEC (@DynamicQuery)
end
-- END of dynamic SQL
```

Comment: Dear @peter.aryanto, I have the impression that this could work -- adapted to my case. However, the size limit of 3,000 is much too small. Even 5,000 is not enough (there are many PK out there, and the text is quickly quite long)… Trying to change that to `text`is not successful either: `The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables.`.

Comment: I did have a thought that you might have such a long query chain. That was the reason I chose varchar (max 8000) instead of nvarchar (max 4000). Would 8000 characters be enough?

If that is still not enough, SQL Server has varchar(max) that has 2GB limit (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I've used `varchar(max)` but am still blocked. When replacing `EXEC` by `PRINT`, I see that the string is cut at 8,000 chars!?

Comment: To check the long string, please use `PRINT LEN(@DynamicQuery)` or `EXEC ('select ''' + @DynamicQuery + '''')`.

Unfortunately, `PRINT` command/statement will truncate long string at 8,000 characters (it has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392161/t-sql-varcharmax-truncated/7392209#7392209).

Comment: Just a quick double check to proof that it is not truncated: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e19841baa154fc58ce3662b725577243

Comment: The counter and its limit at 90 are not clear to me (would you mind explaining?).

Comment: But I've successfully changed the queries to my case, and could run the whole thing with no size problem anymore. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you've finally solved the case :)  By the way that loop with counter and limit at 90 is just to build up long query/text that exceeds 8000 characters (just a quick "hacky" test setup).